# Magento Email htmlescape not working

Tags: magento-2.1, email-templates

I am trying to set up the emails for a Magento 2 site.

Part of my email template is:

```
Dear {{htmlescape var=$customer.name}} ,
```

Unfortunately, when the email is sent, I get

```
Dear {{htmlescape var=$customer.name}} ,
```

Rather than

```
Dear John Smith ,
```

Interestingly, it appears to be only the variables with htmlescape in them that are the problem. `{{var store.getFrontendName()}}`, for example, is correctly processed.

I inserted the code using the "Insert Variable" button so it isn't  a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to worry about escaping.
In 2.1 the escape is applied automatically

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Email/Model/Template/Filter.php#L612

all you need to write is `{{var customer.name}}`.
but if you want it the other way around, without escaping you can do this

```
{{var customer.name|raw}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I tried that but now I am just getting `Dear ,`, no name or variable

Comment: I made some changes. I dropped the `$` sign. Maybe it works like that.

Comment: Is there somewhere that documents what modifiers are available? (stuff such as the |raw) Also, is there one for either rounding off float values to 2 decimal precision and/or displaying currency properly?